# Get consecutive sequence number in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to display row number sequence of each group.

I have used $V{PAGE_COUNT}  and evaluation time as now

The report data that I am getting is 
Group A

1.

2

3

4

...........

page ends ......

Group A

1

2

3

4

page ends ---------

Group B

1

2

3

4

5

page ends....

But my requirement is

Group A

1.

2

3

4

...........

page ends

Group A

5

6

7

8

9

page ends .......

Group B

1

2

3

4

5

page ends....

I need all rows of same group to be continuous sequence. And start sequence from 1 when group is changed

Comment: You should use the `$V{groupA_COUNT}` (depends on your group's name) variable. It is created automatically when you added a group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `GroupName_COUNT` variable in this case.

The quote from the [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)

> ```
> When declaring a report group, the engine automatically creates a count variable that
> calculates the number of records that make up the current group (that is, the number of
> records processed between group ruptures).
> The name of this variable is derived from the name of the group it corresponds to,
> suffixed with the _COUNT sequence. It can be used like any other report variable, in any
> report expression, even in the current group expression, as shown in the BreakGroup
> group of the /demo/samples/jasper sample)
> ```

More info is here: [Data Grouping](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/jasper/index.html#groups)